# ListView Adapter with Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, listview-adapter

I am using a custom adapter to list some user, I want to list some picture throw `Firebase`, I am using `Picasso` for that but I can not show the picture in the list, in step it show the url.

This is the Adapter:

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserInformation> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;


public customAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<UserInformation> userInformationsList) {
    super(context, layoutResource, userInformationsList);

    this.context=context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.userslist, null);
    }

    UserInformation userInformation = getItem(position);

    if (userInformation != null) {
        TextView Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNameList);
        //name.setText(name[position]);
        ImageView mPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPicture);
        String uri ;
        //email.setText(Email[position]);
        TextView gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textGenderList);
        //gender.setText(Gender[position]);
        TextView birthday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBirthdayList);
        //birthday.setText(Birthday[position]);

        if (Name != null) {
            Name.setText(userInformation.getName());
        }
        if (mPicture != null) {
            uri=(userInformation.getUri());
            Picasso.with(context).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(mPicture);

        }
        if (gender != null) {
            gender.setText(userInformation.getGender());
        }
        if (birthday != null) {
            birthday.setText(userInformation.getBirthday());
        }
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Capture]

This is the .XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorEditText">


<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPicture"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNameList"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textEmailList"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="Age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textBirthdayList"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="Birthday"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textGenderList"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="gender"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any sugestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there errors in the logcat from Picasso saying images aren't loading?

Comment: Try and hit url on browser if it works then only it will work in picasso

Comment: share your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add url to picasso check weather is valid url or not, if valid then try this piece of below code in `getView()` also remove `fit().centerCrop()` because if image is large it will not set.
if you add `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` property in xml then remove this also. and check in `Manifest` you add or not Internet permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and use this:

```
if (mPicture != null) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(userInformation.getUri()).into(mPicture);
   }
```

Hope it will help.